# `sudo: command not found' when following a tutorial for Let's Encrypt

Tags: rhel, sudo

I'm following a [Godaddy help tutorial](https://fr.godaddy.com/help/install-a-lets-encrypt-ssl-apache-20245) in order to install Let's Encrypt certificate for my website. So I connected to my server using `ssh` via `Putty`.

Typing the command `sudo git clone https://github.com/letsencrypt/letsencrypt` gives me get the error `-bash: sudo: command not found`.

After typing `cat /proc/version` I found that I have a Red Hat dist, so what should I do?

Comment: Is git installed? What is the output of `which git`?

Comment: the output is : /usr/bin/git
when installing git using the tutorial https://fr.godaddy.com/help/how-to-install-git-on-linux-web-hosting-12391 I modified the file ~/.bash_profile manually using cat >> so I think it's the problem.

Comment: What about `which sudo`? If it's not there, it may need to be installed: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-ubuntu-rhel-centos-linux-bash-sudo-command-not-found/

Comment: which sudo gives no output.

Comment: If you do not wish to install sudo, just become root and run the commands.

Comment: What is their reason for wanting people to run `git clone` as root anyway? I can't imagine why that would ever be necessary.

Comment: Looking at the instructions, its absolutely unnecessary to run `sudo git ...`.  Whoever wrote those instructions is very confused.  If you look at the [letsencrypt-auto](https://github.com/certbot/certbot/blob/master/letsencrypt-auto) script, it will run sudo if necessary.

Answer (score 7):

To resolve the error message, you may need to install `sudo` using the steps below. Alternatively, you could run the command after logging in with the root account using `su -`.

To install `sudo`:

Log in with the root account using `su -`. Then, `yum install sudo`.

After that is installed, add the user's account to the `/etc/sudoers` file.

After the following line:

```
## Allow root to run any commands anywhere
root    ALL=(ALL)       ALL
```

Append this line:

`user   ALL=(ALL) ALL`

See [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-ubuntu-rhel-centos-linux-bash-sudo-command-not-found/) for more info.

Comment: even su  or yum gives the same error, P.S: I typed ls /bin and I didn't find su or sudo

Comment: Perhaps this will solve the issue?

https://fr.godaddy.com/help/enable-adminroot-access-managed-or-fully-managed-12270

Comment: @Hamza sudo is installed in an sbin directory and not the bin directory. You will have to search either /sbin or /usr/sbin. In either case can you paste the output of `which su`

Comment: which su gives no output, and checked the 2 dirs but no presence of su or sudo.

Comment: Did you try enabling admin/root access in the Godaddy control panel, according to the previous link?

Comment: yes I'm trying to do so, but can't find it in Godaddy

Answer (score 1):

Sudo is a popular command for raising a normal user's privileges.

I'd guess that you are logging in directly as root, in which case there's no need to use sudo - everything you do is already sudoed, effectively.

Comment: My server in Godaddy is a shared hosted server, after asking I found that I can't have the root access to the server.

Comment: No root access : Then please never use  `sudo` . Not required for `git clone https://github.com/letsencrypt/letsencrypt` .

Answer (score 0):

To highlight Knud Larsen's (and other users) comment, `sudo` isn't required here. You can use `git` when logged into GoDaddy's SSH without `sudo`.

In PuTTY, simply use:

```
git clone https://github.com/letsencrypt/letsencrypt
```

**That being said**, actually installing Let's Encrypt also requires `sudo` level access further along the process which is not granted to shared accounts. I have yet to find a workaround to have Let's Encrypt work at all on a GoDaddy Shared account. Off to a better host I go.