# letencrypt on shared hosting: neither yum or dnf found

Tags: yum, ssl, letsencrypt

I am following the directions on the following site
https://www.godaddy.com/help/install-a-lets-encrypt-ssl-apache-20245

and per this question
[`sudo: command not found' when following a tutorial for Let's Encrypt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/291993/sudo-command-not-found-when-following-a-tutorial-for-lets-encrypt?newreg=c270ac1ead834cf98d6d59b1cd80f78c)

i skipped the sudo and just git cloned the lets encrypt lib onto my shared host
godaddy

```
git clone https://github.com/letsencrypt/letsencrypt
```

but now when i attempt the command

`./letsencrypt-auto --apache -d your domain name`

I receive the error

```
Neither Yum nor DNF found
```

because its a shared server, i cannot install yum as i am not the root user, is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

The steps outlined in the GoDaddy link (in the question section) will not work with shared hosting account.

**With GoDaddy shared hosting account you don't have root access,** which is required by letsencrypt official client.

**To workaround this you can use third party letsencrypt client** called [acme.sh](https://github.com/Neilpang/acme.sh) which is advertised as:
"*Purely written in Shell with no dependencies on python or the official Let's Encrypt client*", this allows it to works with shared hosting accounts.

**Note** that while [acme.sh](https://github.com/Neilpang/acme.sh) will generate letsencrypt certificate for you, I was unable to install it automatically (through shell scripting), for that I  unfortunately use GoDaddy cPanel UI.

**Generate letsencrypt certificate.**

1. Install acme.sh following official documentation.
2. Issue certificates.

   New certificate

   ```
   acme.sh --issue -d domain.com -d www.domain.com -w /home/username/www
   ```

   Or after 90 days when you have to renew.

   ```
   acme.sh --renew -d domain.com -d www.domain.com --force
   ```
3. Install the cert in GoDaddy cPanel.

While not specific for acme.sh, I personally found this guide very helpful.
https://isabelcastillo.com/lets-encrypt-ssl-certificate-godaddy-shared-cpanel

You can start from *"Part 3: Install The SSL Certificate in Your GoDaddy cPanel Hosting Account"*

Alternatively you can try to follow isabelcastillo.com guide and use his tool of choice, though in my experience acme.sh is easier to use.